# Wrong number of arguments when using mget with redis-rs

Tags: redis, rust

I'm trying to access Redis using Rust with the following:

```
extern crate redis;

use redis::{Client, Commands, Connection, RedisResult};

fn main() {

    let redis_client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    let redis_conn = redis_client.get_connection().unwrap();

    let mut keys_to_get = vec![];
    keys_to_get.push("random_key_1".to_string());
    keys_to_get.push("random_key_2".to_string());
    let redis_result: String = redis_conn.get(keys_to_get).unwrap();
}
```

When I run `cargo run` I get:

```
     Running `target/debug/test_resdis`
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: An error was signalled by the server: wrong number of arguments for 'get' command', ../src/libcore/result.rs:746
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
error: Process didn't exit successfully: `target/debug/test_resdis` (exit code: 101)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your program against a netcat server shows the following requests made:

```
*3
$3
GET
$12
random_key_1
$12
random_key_2
```

The `GET` command should be an `MGET`.

---

I believe this to be a [bug in the implementation](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs/blob/9e4f975e62d7f64dc672ee0f40f1628a4defe41c/src/types.rs#L518-L532):

```
impl<T: ToRedisArgs> ToRedisArgs for Vec<T> {
    fn to_redis_args(&self) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
        ToRedisArgs::make_arg_vec(self)
    }
}

impl<'a, T: ToRedisArgs> ToRedisArgs for &'a [T] {
    fn to_redis_args(&self) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
        ToRedisArgs::make_arg_vec(*self)
    }

    fn is_single_arg(&self) -> bool {
        ToRedisArgs::is_single_vec_arg(*self)
    }
}
```

Under the hood, the library inspects the key type to know if it's multivalued or not, using `ToRedisArgs::is_single_arg`, which has a default implementation of `true`.

As you can see, a slice implements `ToRedisArgs::is_single_arg`, but a `Vec` does not. This also suggests a workaround: treat the vector like a slice:

```
redis_conn.get(&*keys_to_get)
```

[This issue has now been filed with the library](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs/issues/95).

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs/issues/95 Thank you for your support.

Comment: mitsuhiko (redis-rs creator) already fixed it, and should be on the next release